# How klog logs to stdout as well as files files

Tags: go, kubernetes

I'm working on a project that uses the `klog library` for logging, and I want to be able to write the `logs to a **terminal** while being able to write to a **file**` for viewing on reboot or downtime.

I tested through the following code, but it can only write to the file and not output at the terminal at the same time

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "k8s.io/klog/v2"
)

func init() {
func init() {
    var fs flag.FlagSet
    klog.InitFlags(&fs)
    fs.Set("logtostderr", "false")
    fs.Set("log_file_max_size", "1000")
    fs.Set("log_file", "/home/test/workspace/test/test.log")
}
}

func main() {
    defer klog.Flush()
    klog.Info("test")
}
```

How can I get it? I really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: in the context of k8s, what exactly do you mean by "write logs to a terminal"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [Klog documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/klog/v2#section-documentation) says that it supports a flag, `-alsologtostderr`:

> `-alsologtostderr=false`
> Logs are written to standard error as well as to files.

Seems like that would do you.